# Why am I obtaining this MappingException trying to convert an Hibernate entity class instance into its DTO class instance?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, dto

I am working on a Spring Boot using **Spring Data JPA** and **Hibernate** mapping application and I am finding some difficulties trying to convert an instance of an entity class into its DTO version. Following I will describe the situation.

First of all this is my **User** entity class containing the Hibernate mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "portal_user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User implements Serializable {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5062673109048808267L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.firstName.Validation}")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;
    
    @Column(name = "surname")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.surname.Validation}")
    private String surname;
    
    @Column(name = "sex")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.sex.Validation}")
    private char sex;
    
    @Column(name = "birthdate")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.birthdate.Validation}")
    private Date birthdate;
    
    @Column(name = "tax_code")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.taxCode.Validation}")
    private String taxCode;
    
    @Column(name = "e_mail")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.email.Validation}")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "pswd")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.pswd.Validation}")
    private String pswd;
    
    @Column(name = "contact_number")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.User.contactNumber.Validation}")
    private String contactNumber;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private boolean is_active;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "address")
    private Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "portal_user_user_type", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "portal_user_id_fk") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id_fk") }
    )
    private Set<UserType> userTypes;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonProperty("subagent")
    private User parent;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "user-wallets")
    private Set<Wallet> wallets = new HashSet<>();


    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public User(String firstName, String middleName, String surname, char sex, Date birthdate, String taxCode,
            String email, String pswd, String contactNumber, Date createdAt, boolean is_active) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.taxCode = taxCode;
        this.email = email;
        this.pswd = pswd;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.is_active = is_active;
    }
    

}
```

Then I have created this **UserDTO** class that contains the same fields of the previous entity class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDTO {
    
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String surname;
    private char sex;
    private Date birthdate;
    private String taxCode;
    private String email;
    private String pswd;
    private String contactNumber;
    private Date createdAt;
    private boolean is_active;
    
    private Set<UserType> userTypes;
    private User parent;
    private Set<Wallet> wallets;        

}
```

Then I created this **ToUserDTOConverter* class implementing the **Converter** interface, this should be the class used to convert the **User** entity class into the **UserDTO** DTO class:

```
@Component
public class ToUserDTOConverter implements Converter<User, UserDTO> {
    
    @Autowired
    ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Override
    public UserDTO convert(User source) {
        
        UserDTO result = modelMapper.map(source, UserDTO.class);
        
        return result;
    }

}
```

I also created the converter class implementing the inverse behavior (from an **UserDTO** instance to a **User** instance), this one:

```
@Component
public class ToUserConverter implements Converter<UserDTO, User> {
    
    @Autowired
    ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Override
    public User convert(UserDTO source) {
        
        User result = modelMapper.map(source, User.class);
        
        return result;
    }

}
```

Then into my service class (named **UserServiceImpl**) I injected a **ConversionService** instance:

```
@Autowired
ConversionService conversionService;
```

in the same **UserServiceImpl** class I defined this service method:

```
@Override
public UserDTO activateDeactivateUser(int userId, boolean isActive) throws NotFoundException {

    User retrievedUser = this.userRepository.findById(userId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID or email %s was not found", userId)));

    retrievedUser.set_active(isActive);
    this.userRepository.save(retrievedUser);

    return conversionService.convert(retrievedUser, UserDTO.class);
}
```

As you can see it retrieve a **User** instance from the DB, update it and finally it should convert the  retrieved **User** object into an **UserDTO** object to be returned.

Here I have some problem. I created the following unit test method:

```
@Test
@Order(3)
public void activateDeactivateUserTest() throws NotFoundException {
    
    UserDTO retrievedUser = this.userService.activateDeactivateUser(50, false);
    
    assertTrue(retrievedUser.getFirstName().equals("Renato") && retrievedUser.getSurname().equals("Gialli"), "The retrieved user is: Renato Gialli");   
    assertTrue(retrievedUser.is_active() == false);
    
    retrievedUser = this.userService.activateDeactivateUser(50, true);
    assertTrue(retrievedUser.is_active() == true);  
}
```

Performing this method what happens is that (I checked it in debug mode):

1. It correctly enter into the **activateDeactivateUser()** service method to be tested, here it correctly retrieve and unpdate my **User** object.
2. Then when it try to executed the conversion of the **User** object into the **UserDTO** object --> it entered into the **convert()** method of the previous **ToUserDTOConverter** class (as expected). But when it try to execute this line:

   UserDTO result = modelMapper.map(source, UserDTO.class);

it throw a **ConversionFailedException** (the strange thing is that it doesn't print the excpetion details in my stacktrace but i can see it with the debugger). In particular it seems to have this message:

```
org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter@c50d1b2 failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet to java.util.Set.
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.easydefi.users.entity.User.userTypes, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:168)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.util.Iterables.getLength(Iterables.java:50)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter.convert(MergingCollectionConverter.java:44)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter.convert(MergingCollectionConverter.java:31)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.convert(MappingEngineImpl.java:306)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:109)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.setDestinationValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:245)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:187)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:151)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:114)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:71)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:573)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:406)
    at com.easydefi.users.converter.ToUserDTOConverter.convert(ToUserDTOConverter.java:20)
    at com.easydefi.users.converter.ToUserDTOConverter.convert(ToUserDTOConverter.java:1)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:386)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175)
    at com.easydefi.users.service.UserServiceImpl.activateDeactivateUser(UserServiceImpl.java:175)
    at com.easydefi.users.service.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a3f57390.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.easydefi.users.service.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fcf9794.activateDeactivateUser(<generated>)
    at com.easydefi.users.service.UserServiceTest.activateDeactivateUserTest(UserServiceTest.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt....
```

Why am I obtaining this error? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it? I suppose that maybe it could depend by the fact that some fields of the entity class are lazy loaded or something like this...I am going crazy to figure out how to solve this issue.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:** After an additional test I discovered that the problem it should be caused by the following 2 fields of the entity class:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(
    name = "portal_user_user_type", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "portal_user_id_fk") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id_fk") }
)
private Set<UserType> userTypes;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonManagedReference(value = "user-wallets")
private Set<Wallet> wallets = new HashSet<>();
```

Commeinging out the corresponding fields into the DTO class:

```
//private Set<UserType> userTypes;
//private Set<Wallet> wallets;
```

it seems that the conversion of these 2 fields is skipped and it works fine. But why? How can I solve to set also these 2 fields?

Answer (score 0):

The associated `UserType`s and `Wallet`s are lazily loaded, which means on access. However, when your mapper accesses those properties of the entity, the corresponding transaction was already committed (it was only active during the repository call, which is annotated with `@Transactional`) and the session has ended, so that the missing information of the associated entities cannot be fetched anymore.

You may consider fetching the needed info directly as part of the repository query, e.g. using entity-graphs: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs

Another option would be to map your DTO before committing the transaction (e.g. using springs declarative transaction management to demarcate transaction boundaries in own services https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch11s05.html), but this can create performance issues: [What is the "N+1 selects problem" in ORM (Object-Relational Mapping)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping)